# MPI Finalize does not return

Tags: java, mpi, parallel-processing

I'm having a problem (I think with MPI.Finalize()). The application ends well in most of the cases, but in some case (where I don't see anything really strange) the application does not end: all the processes  reach MPI.Finalize() and stay there in the Running state.

Is this possible or maybe I'm missing something?
If this is possible, what would be the case?

Thank you!

Comment: What implementation of MPI are you using?  
How many ranks are in the reproducer?  Can you get a back trace from each rank?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry. It was a problem with the use of Barrier() and the fact I was shutting down not needed processes at the beginning of the execution. Those killed processes would never call Barrier().